# Limit Pivot Table to only most recent records

Tags: sql, pivot, max

I have a table with the following fields:

```
-location
-metername
-measurement
-measuredate
```

I have written a query to PIVOT this so that each value in the metername column is now its own column. However, I would like to restrict this such that it only displays the most recent meter reading based upon the measuredate field. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT LOCATION, MEASUREDATE, 
    [HEIGHT], [DIAM], [HEIGHT-N], 
    [HEIGHT-W], [HEIGHT-C], [HEIGHT-E], 
    [HEIGHT-S], [DIAM-N], [DIAM-W], 
    [DIAM-C], [DIAM-E], [DIAM-S] 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT LOCATION, MEASUREDATE, METERNAME, MEASUREMENTVALUE 
    FROM MEASUREMENT
) P 
PIVOT 
( 
    SUM(MEASUREMENTVALUE) 
    FOR METERNAME IN ([HEIGHT], [DIAM], [HEIGHT-N], [HEIGHT-W], [HEIGHT-C], 
                        [HEIGHT-E], [HEIGHT-S], [DIAM-N], [DIAM-W], [DIAM-C], 
                        [DIAM-E], [DIAM-S]) 
) AS PVT 
ORDER BY MEASUREDATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at adding `row_number()` to your subquery.  If you partition the data by the `location` and `order by measuredate desc`, then you will generate a unique number for each location, then you can filter the data by that value:

```
SELECT LOCATION, MEASUREDATE, 
    [HEIGHT], [DIAM], [HEIGHT-N], 
    [HEIGHT-W], [HEIGHT-C], [HEIGHT-E], 
    [HEIGHT-S], [DIAM-N], [DIAM-W], 
    [DIAM-C], [DIAM-E], [DIAM-S] 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT LOCATION, MEASUREDATE, METERNAME, MEASUREMENTVALUE ,
      row_number() over(partition by location
                        order by measuredate desc) seq
    FROM MEASUREMENT
) P 
PIVOT 
( 
    SUM(MEASUREMENTVALUE) 
    FOR METERNAME IN ([HEIGHT], [DIAM], [HEIGHT-N], [HEIGHT-W], [HEIGHT-C], 
                        [HEIGHT-E], [HEIGHT-S], [DIAM-N], [DIAM-W], [DIAM-C], 
                        [DIAM-E], [DIAM-S]) 
) AS PVT 
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed497/3)

Comment: This looks great, my only concern is does the row-Number function number the rows the same way each time. I have also come up with a solution involving an inner join within the Pivot query, I will post that below for comparison